# Is it a good idea to use the host computer as proxy of a virtual server hosted into it?

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, proxy

I plan to use a physical proxy between another physical server which is accesses via SSH, and the router, acting as firewall.

Right now I just have 1 physical computer to use for this net structure, so I'm using it as proxy (firewall) for a virtual server hosted into itself (NAT connection mode).

However, while looking for similar uses of virtualization on Internet I'm not finding many cases, so I'm wondering whether I'm missing something and perhaps my idea is not that good or simply useless (thinking in security).

I would appreciate any opinion regarding to this. I'm aware that would be much better to use 2 machines, but would be this still an acceptable "cheaper" option?

Comment: I think people use virtual servers(a server on a virtual machine) all the time, I think that's what a VPS is.

Comment: Thanks, thats my idea, but can you rely on the host as proxy in a similar way that if it was a physical one?

Comment: yeah I think the only reason why it might ever be "unreliable" is PEBCAK specifically if you need to restart your host machine and forget to start the guest, or if you're low on RAM and close your hypervisor and then forget to restart the VM and make sure you have the port forwarding rule set in your hypervisor, between VM and Host

Comment: Lol thanks again barlop, I didn't know that acronym but I'll keep it in mind :) your comment is enough descriptive for me to keep on going with my project; I appreciate it.